# Versioning and upgrading features with SharePoint 2010

Tags: feature, versioning, feature-receiver, feature-upgrade

I've been experimenting with feature version-ing and upgrading in Sharepoint 2010 and found a bunch of blogs, documentations etc. but it is still not very clear to me.

- How does Sharepoint store the feature versions? If I deploy more versions of a feature what happens to the old ones?
- When is update triggered, what triggers it, when does it do it automatically and when do I need to write code or update receivers?
- What should happen after the update with the elements that use the old feature (e.g. I have a content type with an element used by a list and I update the content type what happens to that list) etc.

Could someone explain all of this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris O'Brien has covered this in a lot of depth on his blog:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html

If you still have specific questions, then it's recommend to open a separate question for each on this site, as we can then target specific answers, and this also helps other people find specific answers to their own questions.

Comment: I've read that article already. It's good, but I was looking for something with "the context attached". But you are right, this is too broad of a question. I'll ask others more specific. Just for the record, I've found [this one](http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/using-the-featureupgrading-event-to-upgrade-features-sharepoint-2010/) to be good also.

Comment: Another good [one here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/11/17/application-lifecycle-management-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010.aspx); scroll to the bottom :D